# System Settings is not working after upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, system-settings

Recently I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.10. After upgrade lot of things are not working correctly. If I click **System Settings** in the top right corner, nothing happens. Even if I search settings on search bar, nothing is shown. If I try to go to the settings from **Text entry settings**, it shows as below. If I click on **All Settings** here, nothing happens.

[image: system setting broken]

**Edit**

After `unity-control-center` executing this command, I got this

[image]

Comment: what error message do you get when you run system settings on terminal? the command is `unity-control-center`

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel I have edited my question

Comment: what happened on the terminal?